# Organisation is not showing in tower

Tags: github, git-tower

I just got added to a new organisation in github. Git tower is not showing this new organisation in the app. I have tried refreshing, and even unhooking my github account and re-adding it. But still the organisation does not show on the left side. From the git-tower docs:

> When you add a service account to Tower, we automatically check if
>   this account belongs to any organization / team / group.
>
> If so, these will automatically be added to the list of available
>   service accounts in Tower's sidebar: they are available as sub-items
>   to the respective personal account. Click the disclosure triangle
>   button on the left to expand them in the sidebar.

Is there something I have to do to make this organisation show in git-tower? The organisation is set to private on github.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Could it be you're using OAuth to connect to GitHub?
In this case, you'll need to grant access to your organizations' for 3rd party apps like Tower.

You can do this via GitHub on the app's settings page:

- [Setting for Tower on macOS](https://github.com/settings/connections/applications/2b869ca0c7f81a86aac6)
- [Setting for Tower on Windows](https://github.com/settings/connections/applications/c7d9876779218f4b0b1f)

<sub>Disclaimer: I was with the support team for Tower at the time of writing.</sub>

Comment: thanks man, I see that this would work. What I did was to just git clone the repo in terminal, then drag the project folder into tower.

Comment: Holy "wow not obvious and completely hard to find".  But yep, that did it.  Thank you for posting here, really appreciate it

Comment: I did this but the owner didn't get an email, any idea how to access the approval page ?

Comment: Late to the party but this answer just saved me hours of searching!

Comment: I know this was a long while ago.. but this just saved me a lot of time trying to figure this out - when github is chosen as the provider in the tower app, could it not suggest that that setting needs to be changed on the github portal?